# Create a Book in Open Graph without an ISBN number

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We are trying to markup book pages on our site so that those pages map to the Open Graph and are clearly identified to Facebook as book pages. One of the items needed for the markup is the International Standard Book Number or ISBN#.

However, many books (especially e-books) don't have ISBN numbers and for those books Facebook rejects the identification of that object as a book. If a book doesn't have an ISBN number, what would you provide for this tag?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Facebook issue:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/238075889669083

As a workaround, it seems you can use the older open graph type `book`

```
<meta property="og:type" content="book"> 
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/5126EaBrekL.jpg">
<meta property="og:title" content="Frankie in Paris">
<meta property="book:release_date" content="2012-12-17 00:00:00 UTC">
```

instead of the newer `books.book` open graph type

Comment: Have you actually tried this?  In my testing, I got an error when attempting to publish a books.wants_to_read action with a "book" object instead of a "books.book" object.

Comment: I have not tried the books.wants_to_read action. Only the og.like action. Perhaps it would be worthwhile to file a bug with Facebook concerning the wants_to_read action and books without isbn.